# How to get a tuple of arbitrary values from a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

How can I get a tuple of arbitrary values from an anonymous dictionary?

```python
def func():
    return dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)

# How can the following 2 lines be rewritten as a single line,
# eliminating the dict_ variable?
dict_ = func()
(one, three) = (dict_['one'], dict_['three'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An intermediate variable is probably preferable (more readable) than this one-liner:

```
>>> (one,three) = (lambda d:(d['one'],d['three']))(func())
```

(which really does nothing other than move the intermediate value into a function which is generated on the fly)

Comment: Agreed; both mine and yours are more ugly than necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  Note that I wasn't asking for the preferred way, only for possible alternatives.  Only then can I make a style choice.  And thus far, I agree that the intermediate variable is more clear than the 3 alternatives offered.  And of the 3 alternatives thus far, I like yours the best.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the `func()` result?

```
one, three = [v for k, v in sorted(func().iteritems()) if k in {'one', 'three'}]
```

Replace `.iteritems()` with `.items()` if you are using Python 3.

Demo:

```
>>> def func():
...     return dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
... 
>>> one, three = [v for k,v in sorted(func().iteritems()) if k in {'one', 'three'}]
>>> one, three
(1, 3)
```

Note that this approach requires you to keep your target list in sorted key order, rather a strange limitation for something that should be straightforward and simple.

This is *far more verbose* than your version. There is nothing wrong with it, really.

Comment: this fails, look at your demo result - func()['one'] != 3.

Comment: @ch3ka: fixed; it needed a sort.

Comment: still fails in general case

Comment: That's because the use-case doesn't really require these shenanigans. It works for the general case *if you keep your target list sorted too*.

Comment: well, but this just "works" because sorted(['one', 'three']) is ['one', 'three']. consider different names, and it breaks.

Comment: @ch3ka: You need to keep your *targets* in sorted key order. It doesn't matter what the names are otherwise, the point is to provide a *consistent* and *predictable* ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, an intermediate dict is fine in most cases.
readability counts.
If you really find yourself far too often in this situation, you could use a decorator to monkeypatch your function:

```
In     : from functools import wraps

In     : def dictgetter(func, *keys):
  .....:     @wraps(func)
  .....:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  .....:         tmp = func(*args, **kwargs)
  .....:         return [tmp[key] for key in keys]
  .....:     return wrapper

In     : def func():
   ....:         return dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
   ....: 

In     : func2 = dictgetter(func, 'one', 'three')

In     : one, three = func2()

In     : one
Out    : 1

In     : three
Out    : 3
```

or something like that.

Of course, you could also monkeypatch so that you specify your desired fields on calltime, but then you'd want an ordinary function which wraps these mechanics, I guess.

This would be implemented very similar to the body of def wrapper above, and used like

```
one, three = getfromdict(func(), 'one', 'three' )
```

or something like that, but you could also re-use the whole decorator above:

```
In     : two, three = dictgetter(func, 'two', 'three')()

In     : two, three
Out    : (2, 3)
```